# keep .gitattributes updated for git-lfs

Tags: git, git-lfs

I am trying to deploy git-lfs. An issue I'm trying to resolve is if user A decides to add a new file (blah.b), and he says git lfs track blah.b (b/c he learned that binaries must be tracked). Great, now blah.b is tracked. He then adds blah.b, commits it, and pushes it to the repo.

blah.b is now on the LFS server.

User B now pulls from origin and gets blah.b.

1. blah.b is not pulled from LFS server - b/c .gitattributes isn't updated.
2. He manages to call git lfs pull, and now updates blah.b to blah.b`. He may now push a binary to the server b/c he doesn't have .gitattributes.

Is there any way to enforce updating of .gitattributes at push time to make sure this issue doesn't occur?

Thanks